# How to configure max.poll.interval.ms for Kafka REST proxy clients

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Tell me please if it is possible to configure the parameters of consumers that connect to Kafka through a Kafka REST proxy server?

I tried setting max.poll.interval.ms in /etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties
`max.poll.interval.ms=430000`
but that didn't work and the consumer was created with default settings:
`max.poll.interval.ms = 300000`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the site https://developer.confluent.io/get-started/rest/#introduction, I found out that it can be done like this:
I have specified in the docker file

```
KAFKA_REST_CONSUMER_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS: 464000
```

and the parameter appeared in the config file

```
[appuser@rest-proxy ~]$ cat /etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties
consumer.max.poll.interval.ms=464000
```

When creating a consumer, the kafkarest is written in the log file:

```
rest proxy | [2023-09-05 20:26:49,298] INFO ConsumerConfig values:
..
rest-proxy | client.id = consumer-cg1-3
rest-proxy | group.id = cg1
rest-proxy | group.instance.id = null
...
rest proxy | max.poll.interval.ms = 464000
rest proxy | max.poll.records = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's currently not possible to configure this property for rest proxy:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/production-deployment/rest-proxy/config.html